# Eclipse Freezes Constantly

Tags: eclipse

I've heard rumors about "Eclipse's minute of silence", but I had no idea how bad it is.

I've installed a brand new Eclipse (from a ZIP package) and only installed the JBoss tools. Now Eclipse freezes at close to each key shortcut, but at least once every 30 seconds. Ctrl+C? One minute Freeze. Doesn't copy. Ctrl+D? One minute freeze. Also, doesn't delete any lines. Clicking into an editor? One minute freeze. It also takes everything with it, so e.g. my browser won't work while Eclipse freezes.

It is not possible to work like this. At all. My colleagues just went back to Eclipse 2018-09, but I need Java11, so I can't.

I could not find any bugs for this issue (a lot of bugs for Eclipse freezing, but none that should still be present in 2018-12).

Anyone else experienced something like that? It's our entire office, so it's not just one faulty computer. Could it have something to do with how Eclipse scatters its config files over the hard drive? Maybe it can't read the 2018-09 config files or something?

Comment: Turn on GC logging in the Eclipse JVM and see if your freezes correlate with the GC.  (I've had problems with previous Eclipse versions due to trying to work on a project that was too large for the JVM's heap.  This lead to lots of GC pauses.)

Comment: Another thing is that Eclipse does not perform well if you install it on a remote file system mount, or if the project is on a remote file system mount.

Comment: @StephenC During the freeze there are no changes to the memory requirements (so GC ist not necessary). Eclipse doesn't even use the CPU fully. And it's a standard local installation in *C:\Programs*.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `Project Explorer`, this could be caused by bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536918 which is already fixed for Eclipse 4.11 (and will be released as Eclipse 2019-03 in March)

You can use an integration build from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

As workaround, it might also help to to close the `Project Explorer` View (in all perspectives) and use the `Package Explorer` instead.

As others have written, it might also be a memory issue. Open the Eclipse Preferences and
in the `General` section enable `Show heap status` so you can see it at the bottom of the window.
If this is the problem, edit eclipse.ini and increase the memory settings (open eclipse.ini and increase the number of the line with -Xmx. If you have a mac, right-click on the Eclipse Application, choose Package Contents, find it at Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini)

Comment: I have 4.11 and it continues freezing on big projects.

Comment: We are using eclipse 2019-09 and, for what its worth, performance has degraded heavily for ALL the "2019"-versions (we worked with the 2019-03 and 2019-06 versions, too). We are facing steady "freezes" of almost one minute (during code completion, organize imports ...). During build/compilation, the mouse pointer lags so other applications are almost unusable (unless the priority of eclipse & java compiler is reduced to "Low" in Windows). However, I have to admit that this might have to do with the switch to JDK 10 (we used JDK 8 with the former 2018 versions).

Comment: Using 2021-03, it takes forever and a day for practically anything! Working with it feels like wading through molasses and I am soon "cooked enough" to switch to IntelliJ... :-(

Comment: The issue from my answer has long been fixed. Either it is a new issue, or you changed something in your workspace so an older problem is triggered (e.g. using worksets as toplevel elements still may lead to freezes, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=450663#c18)

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this "lagging"/"freezing" issue in  Eclipse 2018-12 until I did this.
in eclipse.ini
-Xms256m
**-Xmx4096m**

Of course it has not stopped "freezing" completely, but The number of times has been tremendously dropped.

Comment: thantks for the hint. I will try in 2019-03 (4.11). Hope it could help